# Initial value in "vamin" not finite

Tags: r, optimization, quantitative-finance, volatility

I am trying to fit a multiplicative garch model, following the instructions in http://www.unstarched.net/2013/03/20/high-frequency-garch-the-multiplicative-component-garch-mcsgarch-model/. Though I am using 15 minutes interval for one month. When I run the last command I get the following error: "Error in optim(init[mask], armaCSS, method = optim.method, hessian = TRUE,  : 
  initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite. "  For the daily variance I am using a sample that starts in 2010, otherwise I cannot estimate the daily variance. Tough for the intradaily data, I have data for just one month.  I need to estimate this volatility measure for 110 stocks.

I would really appreciate some help. I don't know how to deal with this problem.

I provide the code, and the error I get for the last command.

```
 sub <- subset(ITCH_volat, ITCH_volat$tickerid == 2,                                     
 select=c(returnmidend, time))
 sub_t <- xts(sub$returnmidend, sub$time)
 C = quantmod::getSymbols('AAPL', from = '2010-03-02',auto.assign=FALSE)
 C = quantmod::adjustOHLC(C, use.Adjusted = TRUE)
 R_d = TTR::ROC(Cl(C), na.pad = FALSE)
 spec_d = ugarchspec(mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(1, 1)), variance.model   
  = list(model = 'eGARCH', garchOrder = c(2, 1)), distribution = 'nig')
 roll = ugarchroll(spec_d, data = R_d['/2013-03-28'], forecast.length = n,     
 refit.every = 5, refit.window = 'moving', moving.size = 5, calculate.VaR =    
 FALSE)# extract the sigma forecast
 df = as.data.frame(roll)
 f_sigma = as.xts(df[, 'Sigma', drop = FALSE])
 spec = ugarchspec(mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(1, 1), include.mean =               
 TRUE), variance.model = list(model = 'mcsGARCH'), distribution = 'nig')
 fit = ugarchfit(data = sub_t, spec = spec, DailyVar = f_sigma^2)
```

The last command gives me the following error:

Error in optim(init[mask], armaCSS, method = optim.method, hessian = TRUE,  : 
  initial value in 'vmmin' is not finite

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I have just realized where my mistake was. By calculating the returns, the first observation was missing, consequently, the error came by having a NaN in the first observation.